# Dropdown to select network to share as hotspot from Windows 10 is disabled

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, iphone, hotspot

When I enabled mobile hotspot in my Windows 10, the settings dialog looks like the screenshot. The Windows system has a wired internet connection.
As you see, the dropdown to select network is disabled.

Why?

When I try to connect to this network with iPhone, I get the error message

> No internet connection

[image]

Comment: Does your Windows have wireless internet connection?

Comment: No, it uses cable to access internet.

Comment: If you own an Iphone older than Iphone 5, then it doesn't support 5GHz band, try sharing it using 2.4 GHz band

Comment: That was the answer!